# Contar vocales en un archivo y saber cuál tiene menos vocales

Tags: python

Me piden que cuente las vocales de la primera columna de un archivo y diga que palabra tiene menos vocales. Lo que estuve haciendo es esto

```
archivo= open("archventa.txt", "r")
leer= archivo.readlines()
dato= lista[0] 
def contar_voc(dato):
      voc= 0
      for c in dato: 
           if c== "a" or c == "e" or c == "i" or c == "o" or c== "u" :
               voc = voc + 1 
      return voc
```

Eso para que cuente vocales y no entiendo cómo hacer para que vea el menor, tendria que usar min?  También pensé en

```
def menor(): 
      menor = lista [0] 
      for valor in lista: 
         if valor < lista:
               menor = valor
       return valor
```

Y sala error

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué error te sale?

Comment: Que no defino la variable valor. Pero nose si estoy interpretando bien el enunciado o hay alguna manera más fácil. Pensé que también podría usar min() y me ahorraría bastantes errores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya que es una tarea académica, no está bien que te la resolvamos. Pero te daré indicaciones de qué tienes mal en el código y cómo abordarlo bien.

La llamada `archivo.readlines()` te devuelve una **lista** en la que cada elemento es una línea del archivo. Estás guardando esa lista en una variable que has llamado `leer` (un nombre mejor sería `lineas`, acostúmbrate desde el principio a elegir buenos nombres para las variables, que indiquen claramente qué contienen).

Más adelante haces `lista[0]`, pero esa variable no está definida. Asumo que querías referirte a `leer[0]`. Esto de cualquier forma es un error de concepto, ya que si teníamos la lista de líneas, usar `[0]` nos da la primera línea, y no la primera columna del fichero.

La primera  columna no la puedes "leer" directamente, pues está formada por la primera palabra de cada línea. Lo que tienes que hacer es iterar por esa lista y para cada elemento tomar sólo la primera palabra. Esa palabra sería lo que le has de pasar como parámetro a tu función `contar_voc()`, que es correcta (aunque yo la llamaría `contar_vocales()`, no escatimes letras en los nombres, son gratis :-) Por cierto que, aunque la función la tenías bien, no la invocabas nunca.

Ya que tienes que iterar por cada línea, cada vez que iteres tendrás un número diferente (las vocales de esa palabra en concreto). Tienes que quedarte con el mínimo de todos los que veas. Hay dos formas de hacer esto:

- Ir guardando en una lista cada número, y al final del bucle cuando hayas recorrido todas las líneas, hacer un `min()` de esa lista.
- Sin lista. Tener una variable en la que guardes el número más pequeño visto hasta el momento. Esa variable comenzará con un valor grande (por ejemplo 1000) y cada vez que, al procesar una línea, veas un número menor del que tenía, le asignas ese nuevo número.

Voy a darte el *pseudocódigo* de la segunda solución, que es más útil para quien está aprendiendo (cuando ya sepas, podrás usar `min()` para ahorrar trabajo).

Este sería:

```
abrir fichero
leer todas las lineas del fichero en una variable llamada lineas
preparar una variable con el minimo visto hasta ahora, con el valor 1000
para cada linea en lineas:
   obtener la primera palabra de la linea
   vocales = contar_vocales(primera palabra de la linea)
   si vocales < minimo visto hasta ahora:
      minimo visto hasta ahora = vocales
```

Para el paso `obtener la primera palabra de la linea`, investiga la función [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

### **Bonus**: truquillo Python

Para ver si `c` es una vocal puedes hacer:

```
if c in "aeiou":
```

El operador `in` sirve para comprobar si una subcadena aparece dentro de otra (o un elemento dentro de una lista).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Entendí las referencias del pseudocódigo e investigue la función str.split(), la utilizo cuando a partir de una cadena quiero llegar a una lista. Pero no sé cuál debería ser el argumento para que me lea solo la primer columna. Por favor si podrías ayudarme en eso que no logro darme cuenta

Comment: `linea.split()` separa la línea por los espacios y te devuelve una lista cuyos elementos son las palabras. Basta quedarse con el elemento `[0]`

Comment: Entonces linea.split() = líneas [0]

Comment: @Amina No, esa asignación no tiene sentido, piénsalo. Al lado izquierdo de una asignación debe haber una variable y no una llamada a función. Si la pones al revés, `lineas[0] =linea.split()` ya no sería incorrecta, pero tampoco hace lo que quieres. Lo que hace es cambiar lo que había en `lineas[0]` (que era la primera línea) por el resultado del split. Lo que necesitas es guardar el resultado del split en otra variable intermedia, por ejemplo `palabras` y después quedarte con `palabras[0]`